# PRESTO SQL: How to get max date from multiple records?

Tags: sql, presto

I'm trying to get the records with the max date also converted from unix time...thanks:

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select t.*, from_unixtime(unix_time) as converted_time
from (select t.*, row_number() over (partition by item_id order by unix_time desc) as seqnum 
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```

Comment: Thanks @Gordon that worked! I just had to add a WHERE clause for type='comment' in the subquery